# Datatables - Create each column from different Laravel queries

Tags: mysql, laravel, datatable, pivot

### What I need

I need to be able to populate a datatables table from 3 different queries. It's basically a pivot table from a single MySql table but I have nothing in common for each row to create a manual pivot table to Group By.

My table basically looks like this:

```
id  |  environment_id  |  |  date  
1  |  1  |  Date1  
2  |  1  |  Date2  
3  |  2  |  Date3  
4  |  2  |  Date4  
5  |  3  |  Date5  
6  |  3  |  Date6
```

What I need is this to be pulled out in to a format that datatables can put in to the following format:

```
environment_id 1  |  environment_id 2 |  environment_id 3  
Date 1  |  Date 3  |  Date 5  
Date 2  |  Date 4  |  Date 6
```

### What I have tried

I tried making a manual pivot table from MySql but because there is no common column to Group By on, it ended up where each row only had 1 column populated at a time leaving big gaps in the table output.

I am currently thinking that I will need to run 3 queries, 1 for each environment_id and somehow concatenate these in to a single array/collection that I can use to populate the datatable with. However, this is proving to be difficult and I can't get my head around how this would work if it's even possible.

Comment: Why are `Date 1  |  Date 2  |  Date 3` in the same row, though they belong to different `environment_id`?

Comment: That's a typo, I've corrected this. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning again.

You sure `groupBy('environment_id')->get()` isnt fullfilling your needs? Because you are trying to achieve an unusual behavior for a datatable. Every information is paired or got an identifier value, as it should be.

Options:

A:
Do single queries and push them in an array.

```
$envArray = [];
foreach ($environment_ids as $id){
    $envArray.push(Environment::where('environment_id','=',$id)->get());
}
```

B:
Define relationships via the ERM Eloquent and call the relationship while the query with `with('dates')`, so called [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

A or B you need to call the arrays inside the array separately for each environment_id when you want to build the table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
    @foreach ($arrays as $array)
        <th>Environment ID {{$loop->iteration+1}}</th>
    @endofreach
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($theLongestArray as $rowindex)
            <tr>
            @foreach ($arrays as $array)
                <td>if ($array[$rowindex]!=null){{$array[$rowindex]}}</td>
            @endofreach
            </tr>
        @endofreach
    </tbody>
</table>
```